# Limiting python filedialog to a specific filetype

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I created the following trial code to make a program that will load an excel sheet into a dataframe and then save that dataframe to another excel sheet (all of the user's choosing)

```
import os
import pandas
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

class Load_Save_Program():

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master

        self.button1=tk.Button(self.master,text="Load",command=self.Load_file)
        self.button1.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.button2=tk.Button(self.master,text="Save",command=self.Save_file)
        self.button2.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.text=tk.Text(master)
        self.text.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)

    def Load_file(self):
        self.df_import=pandas.read_excel(filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = os.getcwd()),
                                            filetypes=("excel files","*.xlsx"))
        self.text.insert(tk.END,self.df_import)

    def Save_file(self):
        self.writer = ExcelWriter(filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = os.getcwd()),
                                            filetypes=("Excel files", "*.xlsx"))
        self.df_import.to_excel(self.writer,'sheet1')
        self.writer.save()

root=tk.Tk()
Load_Save_Program(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What I would like to do is to expand this so that when the program pops up the file directory window, it only shows files that are of the .xlsx filetype as to avoid an error from the user opening up an incompatible file type. So far I've yet to come up with any information that can explain how to set this up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the order is important. Additionally, the answer must include the [] around the filetype. The two lines in question must be

```
self.df_import=pandas.read_excel(filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files","*.xlsx")],initialdir = os.getcwd()))
self.writer = ExcelWriter(filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")],initialdir = os.getcwd()))
```

Comment: I am pretty sure order isn't important (I can't test it out at the moment), but the format of file types _is_ critically important. It needs to be a list of lists (or list of tuples)

Comment: Please feel free to verify this. I'm not sure why it mattered but I tried it several times switching the order and it only worked properly is the filename is in front.

Comment: If anyone needs multiple file types combined as one dialog option, use `("video files","*.avi;*.mp4")`

Answer (score 9):

The filedalogs have a filetypes option to do exactly what you want. The general syntax is `filetypes=[(label1, ext1), (label2, ext2), ...]`.

In your case that will give:

`filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])`

Comment: I made the changes you described (adding the []) and the program ran exactly the same. It was still showing files of other datatypes.

Comment: @jon You need to put the `filetypes=` inside the brackets of `askopenfilename`, which is not the case in your code.

Comment: @jon and that's exactly what you did in your answer.

Comment: This is simply not true. The code in question is in fact inside of the brackets. Whether or not this is proper pythonian code is debatable (it's just how I choose to write it since I don't have auto wrap setup) but this does not have an effect on the code working properly.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, the order (for reasons unknown to me) is the key to this code working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this discussion when looking for a solution to a different problem.
As the accepted answer cost me some time and did not help, I thought I'd clarify:
The order of the kwargs in question for askopenfilename has no relevance.

In fact, I got it working with the exact order stated in the OP.
The problem in the OP comes from misplaced parentheses, as stated in the comment by @j_4321 to the OP.

To sum up: OPs problem can be solved with the following:

Change

```
 def Load_file(self):
    self.df_import=pandas.read_excel(filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = os.getcwd()),
                                        filetypes=("excel files","*.xlsx"))
```

To

```
 def Load_file(self):
    self.df_import=pandas.read_excel(filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = os.getcwd(),
                                        filetypes=("excel files","*.xlsx")))
```

Changing the order of the kwargs when calling askopenfilename is not likely to solve problems.