# How to use askfilename() or similar to get the name of a .url file with Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Epic saves it's shortcuts in a .url file format, I wish to make use of the askopenfilename() function of tkinter to just select the shortcut and then with the code bellow open the directory of the game, but whenever I try such a thing with said function I get a "catastrophic error",is there any way to select it with tkinter.filedialog? or, are there any other functions I could use to achieve the same result?

```
import os
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

target_url = #Here is where I wish to put a fd.askopenfilename() function, but as I described, this doesn't work#
#Thus far the target_url variable is just an input()#


data = open(target_url, mode='r')
data_read = data.read()
data_index = data_read.index("IconFile=")

exe = data_read[data_index:].replace('IconFile=', '')
replaced = os.path.basename(exe)

open_thing_2 = exe.replace(replaced, '')

os.startfile(open_thing_2)
```

For easier debugging, this is a example of the contents of such .url file.

```
[{Number_Array}]
Prop3=19,0
[InternetShortcut]
IDList=
IconIndex=0
WorkingDirectory=C:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games
URL=com.epicgames.launcher://apps/Jaguar?action=launch&silent=true
IconFile=C:\Program Files\Epic Games\Game_Name\Game_Name.exe
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what is a "catastrophic error"? That phrase isn't very helpful. Please describe exactly what happens, including a full traceback if you're getting an error.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46331408/11106801)?

Comment: There is no traceback Bryan, the tkinter prompt just informs me of a "catastrophic error" whenever I try to open the .url file.
It is as useful a phrase to me as it is to you :c

Comment: That was it TheLizzard!
Thank you!!!

Comment: @BryanOakley I have seen the "catastrophic error" message multiple times but in all of those cases I used tkinter with threading. It occurs when tcl just panics and crashes. Some times it will force IDLE to restart.